# Content width of TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

I'm trying to add some content insets in TabView with page style. Is it possible to change TabView content width, so it could show a part of next and previous View? I can easily do it with HStack or ScrollView, but I wonder if I can do it with TabView as well, because TabView has many features I need in this case.

[image: figma disign]
[image: what I have now]

My test code looks like this:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Group {
            ExcursionView(index: 1, count: 3)
            ExcursionView(index: 2, count: 3)
            ExcursionView(index: 3, count: 3)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page)
}
```